# Make widget for an application in android

Tags: android, widget

I already made an application in android. Now my requirement is that i want to make a widget for this application. I have already made an Widget Demo. But i don't know how can i launch my application through Widget Icon.
Please give me a way to do it.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main class:

```
public class Main extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    for  (int i =0 ; i< appWidgetIds.length ; i++)
    {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(context, Home.class);

        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Site, pending);;

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}
```

}

AndroidManifest.xml

```
         <receiver android:name="Main">    
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget" />
        </receiver>
```

Widget.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/Site"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/commentsms" />
```

and in res/xml/widget.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:minHeight="72dp"
     android:minWidth="144dp"
     android:updatePeriodMillis="0" >

    </appwidget-provider>
```

Comment: where i have to add this code ? in my project ? if yes then what i call in place of Home.java ? my first activity is Splash.java. so i replace home.java to splash.java

Comment: you must add class Main to your project.Home is first activity that you want to show,that in your project is splash.class

Comment: ya i done this. Application install but no icon or widget to display in Device :(

Comment: you must add widget manualy,if you test on emulator, go to widget and add widget to your screen

Comment: go to list of app and then in above of screen two tab exist, app and widgets, then clicked widgets and drag your app on screen.i use this code and this must be worked

Comment: sir please edit AndroidManifest.xml in your answer. with adding Splash activity. Because i am confused where i have to paste manifest code. i think it is the problem :(

Comment: you must just add this line to your manifest file after all activity and in application,

Comment: in Res/xml/widget.xml
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="146dip"
    android:minHeight="72dip"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_main"
/> '

Comment: ya, you right, i forgot to add this, i update my post, tnx for your mention